# The advice I've found is to use LTS tools for work, instead can start on a new version if I know the next LTS will come out before project completion?

Tags: architecture, sdlc, enterprise-development

I've had this idea because I've recently had to upgrade a large enterprise project (due to security vulnerabilities) that was completed and not touched for years before I joined, and both the backend (Spring) and frontend (Angular) were so out of date that I'm not sure it's possible to upgrade it since there was no documentation regarding the libraries used, why and where.

This will cost the team more money if they insist on maintaining such things. What if for future projects I do what I suggested, start working on a newer than LTS version (only if I've researched the timeline of LTS release and am sure the migration will be within budget)?

Comment: Why are you asking the Internet rather than explaining the two options to your client?

Comment: Please edit the question to define your meaning of LTS.

Comment: Are you interpretting LTS as [**L**ong **T**erm **S**upport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support)?

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of LTS projects is not the newness, but the length of time to get patches. Not all updates are created equal, and having access to patch-only releases can save time and reduce overall risk of upgrades.

Different products have different meanings for standard and long-term support. For example, Django is 16 months for standard (feature releases happen approximately every 8 months, and the last 2 feature releases are supported) and 3 years for LTS. Debian is 3 years and 5 years. For talking in concrete terms, let's use Debian.

If you were to use the standard Debian release, you would only get support for 3 years. After that, there's no guarantees about things like availability of package repositories or new patch releases. If there were to be a critical vulnerability in year 4, you may be forced to update to a new minor or even major version of Debian. Because it is more than a patch, you will probably need to do a lot more due diligence to ensure that your system continues to function as expected on the new version. There's also a greater chance that you will need to make additional changes to support the new version, and those changes will also drive additional design and testing effort. However, when something is called a patch, the general assumption is that the functionality remains the same minus the repairs to the defects.

A lot of the level of risk does depend on your system. For example, a life critical system may not be able to accept patches without rigorous testing. Even though the intention may be to maintain functionality, the patch may have introduced a regression and those defects would be unacceptable in a system that may cause loss of life. For most systems, though, the amount of change in a component is considered when determining the risks in upgrading that component and the amount of work needed to reduce that risk to an acceptable level.

At the end of the day, the client will have to make the decision based on their tolerance for risk. However, I would not just assume that there will be a budget for upgrading components. Usually, a new LTS version is released before the support for the previous version expires, which gives you a runway to switch. You can plan for the effort needed to not only upgrade the components, but perform all of the necessary testing and any additional changes to support that upgrade while making sure that your system can receive security patches for any critical vulnerabilities.

Comment: FYI Node's support is not 12 and 18 months: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right. I was flipping through a few support pages to get examples. Not sure which one I had that was 12 and 18, though, so I'll just remove that example.

Answer (score 1):

### What is LTS, and who does it benefit?

Some developers/companies chase the latest and greatest technology. Others try to stick with what they used at the time and settle down on this chosen version; not upgrading it until they're forced to.

For the rest of this answer, I will refer to the latest version chasers as "the former group" and the LTS settlers as "the latter group", so I don't have to repeat this constantly.

There is no right and wrong in either of these cases - both have their valid reasons to do so. While the latter group tends to lead to projects that become harder to support in the future; they also avoid a lot of time and effort on upgrades and dealing with feature/interface changes. In the right context, that can be the right decision.

However, the latter group inherently leads to the library developer needing to patch and maintain support on older versions as well as the latest version. If everyone always chased the latest version, the older versions would be obsolete whenever a newer version was released, and the library developer would only need to care about their next version.

LTS versions are intended to be a "rest stop" for those who don't chase the latest version and would prefer to stick with what they have (barring any potential bugs and security weaknesses that have yet to be discovered).

LTS versions act like magnets, trying to pull the former group in towards LTS versions and away from non-LTS versions as much as possible.
By grouping them on these specific LTS versions, the library developer can reduce the amount of old versions that they have to actively support; or at the very least are expected to quickly roll patches out for.

This also works to the benefit of that latter group. LTS versions receive support for longer, which means that they can "rest" at that stop longer than they would be able to for old non-LTS versions.

In other words, LTS versions are a compromise between the library developer and the latter group, making it so that both get a workload that is acceptable to them.

---

### To chase the latest version, or to not chase the latest version?

Having said all that, I think your approach inherently relies on you trying to remain on the fence between these two groups.

> a large enterprise project (due to security vulnerabilities) that was completed and not touched for years

The fact that the company chose to settle on a particular version implies that they knowingly accepted the benefit of having to spend less effort on the version upgrades with the included downside of increased maintenance effort in the future for as long as they don't upgrade.

> What if for future projects I do what I suggested, start working on a newer than LTS version (only if I've researched the timeline of LTS release and am sure the migration will be within budget)?

If your assumption is that you **will** upgrade to the new LTS version when one releases, and you're willing to install newer non-LTS versions in order to keep up to date; then you're actually not in the latter group who chooses to "rest" at the LTS stops. You're squarely in the former group which chases the latest version whenever it is released.

*Note that the version chasers come in different varieties. Some are open to beta versions, whereas others only accest latest versions as they officially release, and others might even only move to a newer version when it has been around for enough time that it has been well documented. All of these fall under the "former group" as I'm labeling them.*
*The main criterion here is that the former group upgrade to a newer version **regardless** of it being LTS or with the intention of sticking with that version for an extended period of time.*

The approach you describe is precisely that of the former group, i.e. the latest version chasers. And that's perfectly fine, but it seems that your company so far has chosen to be part of the latter group.

---

### So what should you do?

This is where we cannot conclusively answer your question. Maybe your company should indeed have invested continual time and effort in keeping up to date with the library. But maybe there are valid reasons for the company not wanting/needing to do so; and your suggestion to do so naively leads to the company eventually having to invest more effort than when they decided to stick with a given version.

If the projects in question do not have a continuous development track, it becomes nigh impossible to chase the latest version, as there are no billable hours available to dedicate towards the upgrade.

> This will cost the team more money if they insist on maintaining such things.

That is a very valid point, and definitely something that you can put to either your management or the customer - whoever it is that decides your billable hours.
What I would avoid, however, is telling them what "the right approach" is. Both approaches come with their own benefits and drawbacks, and the decision needs to be made by them. At best, you can *point out the consequences*; I very much doubt you currently have the authority to make the actual decision.

**In conclusion**

We cannot tell your company what they should and shouldn't dedicate billable hours towards. The only conclusion you can draw here is that the increased threshold of upgrading after a long time is an inherent cost you pay when you settle on a specific version for an extended period.

Comment: I get lost with the "latter group" and "former group" terminology. Maybe "chasers" and "settlers" instead?